# ORA-01422, but Query works fine

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01422

I'm getting absolutely crazy over this.
I'm currently writing a trigger to change some dates around. For that I want to get a max value into a variable like so:

```
SELECT date INTO datevar
               FROM table
               WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date)
                                    FROM table
                                    WHERE condition = loop.condition);
```

The trigger always throws an ORA-01422 (Too many rows returned) on the line of this query; but when I try the query in my sqldeveloper (substituting the loop value with a number) the query works fine, with any data set (works fine = returns exactly one row).

I tried different ways to select the max value into my var, but it's the same problem every time. The loop works fine (when I run the trigger as stored procedure with verbose logging, I see the loop row id's and everything), but it always starts with said error without writing to the database.

I also scoured the web, but I didn't find anything. I'd appreciate any ideas.

Comment: If you have two rows with the same date that happens to be the latest date, this will fail

Comment: While that can fail, and Gordon's simpler approach cannot; are you sure it is that statement that errors? Line numbers in trigger errors are counted from the start of the PL/SQL section (i.e. `declare` or `begin`), not the `create trigger` line, which can be confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you run such a complicated query?  Replace it with:

```
SELECT MAX(date) INTO datevar
FROM table
WHERE condition = loop.condition;
```

This cannot generate such an error.

Comment: This was the fix I found later, but I could've sworn that this was what I tried when I wrote the Query for the first time. Seems to work for now